# Why does RStudio jump back and run the previous code line if there is a star "*" above the line intended to execute?

Tags: r, rstudio

When using Run the current line (by button or `Ctrl+Enter`) and having a code like this (with one or more stars "*"):

```
code line 1
*
code line 2
```

The behavior will be the following:
If one tries to run `code line 1` it runs `code line 1`.
If one tries to run the star line `*` it prints `Error: unexpected '*' in "*"` and then executes `code line 2`.
If one tries to run `code line 2` it runs code `line 1` and the cursor jumps to the star line `*`.

With the "Re-run the previous code region" (`Ctrl+Alt+p`) it seems to work the opposite way.

With the example code the expected behavior would be to run the code line the cursor is on and for the star line `*` print an error if R can't run a star alone but without the cursor jumping or doing it in the normal way (down for normal run and up for 're-run previous code region').

It's not a big issue for me but I do not know why it behaves like this. Posting also in case someone is confused by this behavior and cannot find the reason.

I'm using RStudio Version 1.4.1717 and Linux Mint 20.1 Cinnamon if this is relevant.

Comment: Are you aware that `*` is the multiplication operator and implemented as a function in R?

Comment: @Roland Yes, I am aware, I meant that it can't be run alone, same as other symbols that might need at least a variable or something to operate on. I have been trying and I found that at least with the symbols "/","-","+","(","&" and "^" the behavior is the same as with "*" (seems to be the math and logic symbols). Didn't know if should change the title and content of the question.

Comment: RStudio's behavior ensures that you can run `1 * 2` with a linebreak after `*` regardless of at which of the two lines your cursor is. The issue is that the logic can't deal with binary operators correctly if you have a linebreak before and after the operator. If you try with `1\n+\n2` you will see that unary `+` is called. In my opinion, your coding style shouldn't allow code like in your example.